# Question about Riemannian Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors, information-geometry

I am reading the Riemannian metric and I have some doubts so first let me write everything that I have understood, correct me if I am wrong, thanks
Let $S$ be a manifold. For each point $p\in S$ let us define a map $g:p \mapsto \langle \; , \;  \rangle_p$ where $\langle  \; , \;  \rangle: T_p(S)\times T_p(S)\to \mathbb{R}$ and the inner product satisfies the conditions such as (1)Bilinear,(2) Symmetry and (3) Positive-definiteness,we call this a $\textbf{Riemannian Metric}$ on $S$. and $(S,g)$ is known as $\textbf{Riemannian manifold.}$
so basically we have a map $g$ which maps each point of $S$ to an element of covariant two tensors.
Now let $[\xi^i]$ be a coordinate system for $S$ and $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^i}$then the components $\{g_{ij};i,j=1,2,..,n\}(n=dimS)$ of Riemannian metric $g$ with respect to $[\xi^i]$ are determined by $g_{ij}=\langle (\partial_i)\;,\;(\partial_j) \rangle$ .This is a $C^{\infty}$ function that maps each point $p\in S$ to $g_{ij}(p)=\langle (\partial_i)_p\;,\;(\partial_j)_p \rangle_p$ and let suppose we have $D,D'\in T_p({S})$ then in terms of component we can write it as $D=D^i(\partial_i)_p$ and $D'=D'^{i}(\partial_i)_p$ and the inner product is given by $\langle D\;,\;D' \rangle_p=g_{ij}D^{i}D'^{j}$.
Now I am trying to construct an example for this by taking $S=\mathbb{R^2}$ with the coordinates $\{\xi^1,\xi^2\}$ and we will have $T_{p}\mathbb{R^2}\simeq\mathbb{R^2}$ and then since $(\partial_i)_p$ is the basis of the $T_{p}\mathbb{R^2}$ so simply I have assumed the standard basis $(\partial_1)p=(1,0)$ and $(\partial_2)_p=(0,1)$ and then if we calculate $g_{ij}(p)$ which is given by $g_{ij}(p)=\langle (\partial_i)_p\;,\;(\partial_j)_p \rangle$ then we can calculate all the coefficient and then if we choose any $D,D'\in T_{p}R^2$ such that $D=(2,3)$ and $D'=(2,4)$ then we can calculate the inner product using the above relation of inner product of $D \text{ and } D'$

My question is what is the role of $p$ here since once I defined the basis then at every point I am going to take the same basis throughout and calculate $g_{ij}$ if I change the basis say  $(\partial_1)p=(1,2)$ and $(\partial_2)_p=(2,1)$ then also at every point I am going to take this same basis then what is the role of $p$?? can someone explain it what am I missing,That will be great help.

Comment: 1. (a) The $g_{ij}$ are _functions_ of $p$, not constants. (b) A coordinate basis need not have constant components with respect to the Cartesian basis. 2. As a good-natured writing suggestion, it's helpful to readers when each sentence contains just one idea, and when punctuation is used consistently, e.g., when periods are used to mark the ends of sentences.

Comment: Thank you the comment,actually my doubt is, if $g_{ij}$ is a function of $p$ and if you see the example I am trying to construct so in that $g_{ij}$ does not depend on $p$ ,can you give some example to visualize it.Thanks

Comment: A good example to study is metric and basis in [polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540699/949989).