# Why polar coordinates r basis vector is constant at large r?

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

The Christoffel symbols for polar coordinates r base vector are:

$$\Gamma_{r\theta}^r=0$$

$$\Gamma_{r\theta}^\theta=\frac{1}{r}$$

I understand intuitively why the first one is true: the rate of change of r basis vector in radial direction is zero.

I have difficulty understanding why the second one is true. It says that at large r, the rate of change of r basis vector in azimuthal direction is close to zero. My intuition tells me that the rate of change in azimuthal direction should be bigger (ie. proportional to r).

[image]

To illustrate my confusion, in the diagram above the rate of change of the smaller r basis vector (yellow) is represented by the green arrow. The rate of change of the bigger r basis vector (red) is represented by the blue arrow. So $\Gamma_{r\theta}^\theta$ should be proportional to r.

What am I missing?

Comment: Keyword: contravariant vs covariant basis

Answer (score 2):

First, the vectors should be based at the origin. So the change from a unit vector at angle $\theta$ to a unit vector at angle $\theta+\Delta\theta$ has length approximately $\Delta\theta$, independent of $r$. But at the point $(r,\theta)$, the $\theta$ basis vector has length $r$, and so we need a coefficient of $1/r$. This is the Christoffel symbol you have. But the net vector $\frac 1r \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ is a unit vector, certainly not a vector going to $0$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that it is possible for basis vectors to change size depending on position. So as $r$ gets bigger, the magnitude of $\hat{\theta}$ gets smaller and the magnitude of $\hat{r}$ stays the same?

Comment: No, $\hat\theta$ is always a unit vector, but this is not $\partial\mathbf x/\partial\theta$ when you parametrize by $\mathbf x(r,\theta) = r(\cos\theta,sin\theta)$. Note that $\partial\mathbf x/\partial\theta = r(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ has length $r$. The Christoffel symbols are computed relative to a parametrization!

Comment: @JimmyYang I have learned a lot from writing that [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540699/949989) to a related post. Please dive into it.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      x=r\cos\theta\\
      y=r\sin\theta
    \end{cases}
\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ 
\begin{cases}
      r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
      \theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Calculating the symbol,
$$\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}=\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial r\partial\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial r\partial\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\left(-\sin\theta\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right)+\left(\cos\theta\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\dots=\frac{1}{r}$$
For more see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/567731/331865

Comment: The OP knew how to calculate this. It was a question of geometric heuristics/understanding.

Comment: "I have difficulty understanding why the second one is true"