# What is the unity matrix in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: matrices, change-of-basis, cylindrical-coordinates

If $e_{\rho},e_{\varphi},e_z$ are the unit vectors in cylindrical coordinates, one can check
\begin{align}
(e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho})\cdot (e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho})= e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}, (e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi})\cdot (e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi})= e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi}, (e_{z}\otimes e_{z})\cdot (e_{z}\otimes e_{z})= e_{z}\otimes e_{z}.
\end{align}
which means that the matrices are orthogonal. I suspect that $I=e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi}+e_z\otimes e_z$. At least if one multiplies by a vector one gets back the vector. Is my conjecture true?

Comment: You are confusing me multiple times: If $e_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,,\,e_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,,\,e_3=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,,$ then $e_1\otimes e_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,,\,e_2\otimes e_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,,\,e_3\otimes e_3=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,.$ These matrices are certainly not orthogonal. Idempotent I would say.

Comment: Lastly, what have these properties which hold for all orthogonal vectors to do with cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @KurtG. I'm sorry, the $^{-1}$ is missing. What I meant that these matrices are orthogonal matrices because $A^{-1}=A^t$. But now that you mention it, it does not have to do anything with cylindircal coordinates. It was my observation so far...

Comment: Please look at the matrices I displayed in the first comment. They are not invertible. The only property that holds in your post is $I=e_1\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes e_3\,.$ Without the $^{-1}$ your matrix equations were correct BTW. But your wording was wrong.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks you're right! So what I wrote is also true for cylindrical coordinate basis vectors, i.e. $I=e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi}+e_z\otimes e_z$?

Comment: Yes. It is true in every orthonormal basis when we represent that basis as I did in my first comment. In 2d polar (and likewise in 3d cylindrical) coordinates you can sometimes come across a non-orthonormal basis (called holonomic or coordinate basis). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540699/949989) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: @KurtG. I tried to do this by hand now, $A=(a_{\rho\rho}e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+a_{\rho\varphi}e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\varphi}+a_{\rho z}e_{\rho}\otimes e_{z}+a_{\varphi\rho}e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\rho}+a_{\varphi\varphi}e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi}+a_{\varphi z}e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{z}+ a_{z\rho}e_z\otimes e_{\rho}+a_{z\varphi} e_{z}\otimes e_{\varphi} + a_{zz} e_{z}\otimes e_{z})$. I computed $(e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi} + e_{z}\otimes e_z)\cdot A= A$, but $A\cdot (e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi} + e_{z}\otimes e_z)\neq A$

Comment: The reason is that $(e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\varphi})\cdot (e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho})=0$ so we lose the coefficients $a_{\rho\varphi}$ and $a_{\rho z}$ and the same happens if you go through the second and third line. However, if the matrix is symmetric it is true that $A\cdot (e_{\rho}\otimes e_{\rho}+e_{\varphi}\otimes e_{\varphi} + e_{z}\otimes e_z)= A$. This is not really satisfying...